# Jetpack Compose: Best way to display a start screen only the first time you start the app

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am currently working on an app that has a start screen where I want to input a unique code to add a device through firebase. After adding the first device the menu screen should appear after starting the app.

I currently do that with two Activities and a Shared Preference that checks if I have at least one device and redirects me from the StartActivity to the MenuActivity.

Although that works fine, I don't think it is a good solution. Is there any other way to have a Start Screen that only appears until you entered the first unique code using Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I found this awesome YouTube video, that explains this answer even better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dRwaXH2cYA

---

I know this question is old, but I want to help others finding this while looking for an answer.

The basic Idea would be to have a boolean preference saved in a datastore, that show whether the app has already been opened. The default value would be false, and on every app launch, this preference is checked. If its value is false, you show the screen and then set it to true. When you then relaunch the app, the preference has the value "true" and you don't show the screen. You could archive this, by having an if-statment in the constructor of the Navhost, that controls the "startDestination" value. Something like this:

```
    NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination =
    if(uiState.isFirstLaunch) {
        //set your first launch screen
    } else {
        //default screen
    }
    ){ ...
```

Comment: This YouTube video is actually pretty bad; the `setKeepOnScreenCondition` is wrong and `_isLoading.value = false` is executed in the wrong place.

Comment: The setKeepOnScreenCondition is for the splash screen and has nothing to do with the onBoarding screen, that the question and my answer is about. Same for the _isLoading.value = false

Comment: The point of those two is to overcome the difficulty that the stored `isFirstLaunch` is not available right on launch while it is getting loaded from the `DataStore`. Therefore a splash screen is shown during loading. But in that video it's done wrong (as pointed out by others in the comments as well). I just wanted to save people the time that might be wasted following that tutorial.