# ViewModel - skip start screen Jetpack Compose

Tags: mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I have a start screen(onBoard) and an Auth View Model, I want the screen to skip when I restart. How do I do this via ViewModel?

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.authNavGraph(navController: NavHostController){
    navigation(
        route = Graph.AUTHENTICATION,
        startDestination = Screen.OnBoard.route
    ){
        composable(route = Screen.OnBoard.route){
            OnBoardScreen(navController = navController )
        }
        composable(route = Screen.SignUp.route){
            SignUpScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.CodeInput.route){
            CodeInputScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.AddPassword.route){
            AddPasswordScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Register.route){
            RegisterScreen(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController){
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        route = Graph.ROOT,
        startDestination = Graph.SPLASH, // There's just a switch to Graph.AUTH
        enterTransition = {
            EnterTransition.None
        },
        exitTransition = {
            ExitTransition.None
        }
    ){
        composable(route = Graph.SPLASH){
            SplashScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        authNavGraph(navController)
        composable(route = Graph.TESTS){
            MainScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

I also have NavGraphs with auth and main. Just the same, the transition to main after the auth start screens. I can't do it and I don't understand. I was looking for information, either I'm looking for it badly, or I don't have it. Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried to do it through sharedpreferences, but it didn't work out.

```
data class ScreensUIState(
    var welcomeScreenSkipped: Boolean = false
)
class AuthViewModel(context: Context) : ViewModel() {

    private val TAG = AuthViewModel::class.simpleName

    var registrationUIState = mutableStateOf(RegistrationUIState())
    var screensUIState = mutableStateOf(ScreensUIState())

    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    private fun setFirstLaunch() {
       screensUIState.value = screensUIState.value.copy(
           welcomeScreenSkipped = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("IsFirstLaunch", true)
       )
    }

    fun onEvent(event: UIEvent){
        when(event){
            is UIEvent.WelcomeScreenSkipped -> {
                setFirstLaunch()
            }
```

This answer does not suit me:
[Jetpack Compose: Best way to display a start screen only the first time you start the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880742/jetpack-compose-best-way-to-display-a-start-screen-only-the-first-time-you-star)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for my case I used datastore instead of sharedpref to get data as flow and on the homeViewModel,you can use this logic:

```kotlin
    val startDestination = MutableStateFlow(Screen.Loading.route)

    private suspend fun getStartDestination() {
    
        dataStoreUtils.getIsFirstTime().collectLatest{ isFirstTime ->
                startDestination.value = 
                        if (isFirstTime) Screen.OnBoarding.route
                        else Screen.AuthScreen.route
                    
                }
            }
      }

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getStartDestination()
          }
     }
```

As for datastore use this class:

```kotlin
class DataStoreUtils(
    private val context: Context
) {

    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "user_details")

    suspend fun saveUsersFirstTime(isFirstTime: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[IS_FIRST_TIME] = isFirstTime
        }
    }

    fun getIsFirstTime(): Flow<Boolean> {
        return context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            preferences[IS_FIRST_TIME] ?: true
        }

    companion object {

        private val IS_FIRST_TIME = booleanPreferencesKey("is_first_time")
        private val IS_DETAILS_FILLED = 
        booleanPreferencesKey("is_details_filled")
    }
 }
```

Here the fun getFirstTime() reads from the datastore and updates startDestination while the loading screen is used while this logic is updated so that any other screen won't appear which isn't required.

If you have any more doubts regarding this approach do let me know, as it works perfectly fine for my use case in Jetpack Compose

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, but the mainactivity code would help a lot if you added it.